# Docker Desktop 2.2+ incredibly slow performance with host volume mounts

Tags: windows, docker, mounted-volumes

I've got a build which is quite intensive in terms of file io.  It involves 70k loose files as well as a fair amount of zipping/unzipping.

The performance of this build plummets when run inside of a Docker Desktop 2.2+ container using host volume mounts.

12 minutes - Straight Windows 10

19 minutes - Docker Desktop 2.1.0.5 against **host mounted volume** (Windows /c drive)

71 minutes - Docker Desktop 2.3.0.2 against **host mounted volume** (Windows /c drive)

2 minutes - Docker Desktop 2.1.0.5 against container file system

2 minutes - Docker Desktop 2.3.0.2 against container file system

Even with Docker 2.1.0.5 against host volume mount the performance wasn't great.  But with DD 2.3 going from ~19 minutes to ~71 minutes is mind numbing.

Anyone else seeing this kind of performance hit on file io intensive tasks?

Comment: You might find this discussion useful: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/188

Comment: Sounds like [WSL2](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/188#issuecomment-657477497) or Linux/Unison is the way to go from above GH issue - WinOS mounts are not a high priority area for docker it seems - [even MacOS has filesystem mount consistency flags](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs-caching/)

Answer (score 2):

Take a similar project and had the same problem, I decided to do something simple that is equivalent to the same solution as the docker mount point for developers:

1 - Check if the container has the rsync tool, if not install it.

2 - Generate a shell script file via **dockerfile** with the following instructions:

```
WORKDIR /var/www/html
RUN mkdir -p /folder-shared
RUN echo "#!/bin/bash" > sync-windows-files.sh
RUN echo 'while true; do' >> sync-windows-files.sh
RUN echo '  rsync -avu "/folder-shared/" "/var/www/html"' >> sync-windows-files.sh
RUN echo '  sleep 2;' >> sync-windows-files.sh
RUN echo 'done' >> sync-windows-files.sh
COPY . .
```

Add the command to the last line to run it in the background:

```
CMD ["bash", "-c", "sh sync-windows-files.sh &]
```

Note: My web server is looking at **/var/www/html**, **dockerfile** should always be in the project root, to speed up the process.

3 - Prepare DockerCompose.yml:

```
services:
  regulacao:
    container_name: shared-windows-files
    build:
      context: .
      network: host

    volumes:
      - ./:/folder-shared
    working_dir: /var/www/html/
    ports:
      - "8587:80"
```

Explanation:
The workaround for this problem is to map the docker share to another directory, in this case the directory called **folder-shared** was created in the root of the container image during the build. Once you've mapped the directory, you create a shell script **sync-windows-files.sh** that performs an infinite loop synchronising the files from the **folder-shared** shared folder to the folder where the webserver will point, in my case **/var/www/html**.

By doing this the problem was successfully solved, I hope you can understand.

Answer (score 1):

True story, [x10 times slower in mixed load (reads/writes) according to my benchmarks.](http://making-it-faster.blog/2020/09/14/is-docker-file-system-slow/)

Although they [promise Linux subsystem to be way faster](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-improve-docker-performance-with-wsl2-3a54402ab0f2), it still looks to be [a grey area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62154016/docker-on-wsl2-very-slow).